# http://SPexample.com vs https://SPexample.com

Tags: sharepoint-foundation, url, web-application, https

I have created my web application on http protocol, http://SPExample.com and deploy .wsp solution on it. My application runs on both protocols, i.e http://SPExample.com and on https://SPExample.com. On page load function i have written following code. If i access my application on https protocol, then under Page_Load, what value RootUrl variable will contain? `http://SPExample.com` or `https://SPExample.com`?

```
RootUrl = SPContext.Current.Site.WebApplication.GetAbsoluteUrl();
```

Comment: Debug and see what shows up

Answer (score 1):

The SPContext.Current.Site.WebApplication.GetAbsoluteUrl() will return the URL based on the protocol you are accessing. For example, if you are using http://SPExample.com it will return http://SPExample.com, likewise, https://SPExample.com will return https://SPExample.com. However, as Nadeem mentioned, the best way to verify would be to debug and examine the RootUrl value.

If you are unaware how to debug within a local SharePoint instance, you'll want to set a breakpoint on the the code, and attach your Visual Studio instance to the W3WP.exe worker process. Once the code hits related code, it will let you examine the RootUrl value.